Almost every Hermitian matrix has distinct eigenvalue differences
I know that almost every Hermitian $n \times n$ matrix $A$ has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1$, $\ldots$, $\lambda_n$. (There's a proof in the "spectral dynamics" section of this blog post.)
Can we say that for almost every $A$ the differences $\lambda_i - \lambda_j$ ($i < j$) are distinct? Obviously this is true, but how to prove it?

Here's a proof along the lines of the linked one, without using the resultant, which generalizes to many similar situations.
Let $H$ be the (real) variety of Hermitian matrices with distinct eigenvalues and distinct differences between eigenvalues. Note that $\operatorname{Sym}^n \mathbf{C} \cong \mathbf{C}^n$ as algebraic varieties by the fundamental theorem of symmetric functions, where the map is given by sending $\{\lambda_i\}_i$ to the sequence of coefficients of $\prod_i (X - \lambda_i)$. Thus the map $\alpha\colon M_n(\mathbf{C}) \to \operatorname{Sym}^n \mathbf{C}$ sending a matrix to its set of roots is polynomial (because it is clear that the map sending a matrix to the sequence of coefficients of its characteristic polynomial is a polynomial map). Moreover, there is a polynomial map $\beta\colon\operatorname{Sym}^n \mathbf{C} \to \operatorname{Sym}^{n(n-1)} \mathbf{C}$ sending $\{\lambda_i\}_i$ to $\{\lambda_i - \lambda_j\}_{i \neq j}$. Let $U$ be the subset of $\operatorname{Sym}^{n(n-1)} \mathbf{C}$ consisting of sets without repetition; this is Zariski-open because the corresponding condition in $\mathbf{C}^{n(n-1)}$ is obviously Zariski-open and the natural map $\mathbf{C}^{n(n-1)} \to \operatorname{Sym}^{n(n-1)} \mathbf{C}$ is a quotient map. Note that $H$ is the intersection of $\alpha^{-1}(\beta^{-1}(U))$ with the (real) variety $\mathcal{H}$ of Hermitian matrices. It follows that $H$ is Zariski-open in $\mathcal{H}$. Since $H$ is non-empty, it is Zariski-dense.

I'm afraid I lack the background to understand this proof. What does it mean to say that the map $\alpha$ is polynomial? For instance, the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $\left[\begin{matrix}0&a\cr 1&0\end{matrix}\right]$ is $x^2 - a$, with roots $\pm \sqrt{a}$ --- how can that be polynomial in any sense?

As complex varieties, we have $\operatorname{Sym}^n \mathbf{C}^\times \cong (\mathbf{C}^\times)^n/S_n$, and the map $\operatorname{Sym}^n \mathbf{C}^\times \to \mathbf{C}^n$ above is induced by the corresponding ($S_n$-invariant) map $(\mathbf{C}^\times)^n \to \mathbf{C}^n$, which is polynomial in the sense that it is coordinatewise described by polynomials. In the language of schemes, $\operatorname{Sym}^n \mathbf{C}^\times \cong \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf{C}[x_1^{\pm 1}, \dots, x_n^{\pm 1}]^{S_n}$, which is where the fundamental theorem of symmetric functions comes in. (...)

(...) As you point out, describing the inverse map is more difficult on the level of points, but mainly this is because you first need to choose "algebraic coordinates" on $\operatorname{Sym}^n \mathbf{C}^\times$, which is one way of viewing what the bijection $\operatorname{Sym}^n \mathbf{C}^\times \cong \mathbf{C}^n$ is doing. In any case, throughout the proof you may simply view $\operatorname{Sym}^n \mathbf{C}^\times$ as $(\mathbf{C}^\times)^n/S_n$, an affine variety with coordinate ring $\mathbf{C}[x_1^{\pm 1}, \dots, x_n^{\pm 1}]^{S_n}$, and use the universal property of the quotient.

By the way, the inverse map does indeed send $x^2 - a$ to ${\pm \sqrt{a}}$, and this is a polynomial map. One reason this may be counterintuitive is that this map $s\colon \mathbf{C} \to \operatorname{Sym}^2 \mathbf{C}^\times$ does not lift to a polynomial map $\mathbf{C} \to (\mathbf{C}^\times)^2$ (as square roots are not polynomial). However, if $[2]$ is the squaring map on $\mathbf{C}$, then $s \circ [2]$ does lift to the map $a \mapsto (a, -a)$, which is clearly polynomial. The map $[2]$ realizes $\mathbf{C} \cong \mathbf{C}/{\pm 1}$, so $s \circ [2]$ descends to the map you said.

(Every instance of $\mathbf{C}^\times$ above should instead be $\mathbf{C}$.)

A neighborhood of a self-adjoint matrix $A\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ with distinct eigenvalues looks like
$$
(-1,1)^n \times V .
$$
The first factor varies the eigenvalues while the second chooses normalized eigenvectors. (We can think of $V$ as a neighborhood in
$U(n)/\!\sim$, with $U_1\sim U_2$ if and only if $U_2=U_1\operatorname{diag}(e^{i\alpha_1},\ldots, e^{i\alpha_n})$, but it actually doesn't matter what exactly it is for the purposes of this question.)
If we impose a condition such as $\lambda_1-\lambda_2=\lambda_3-\lambda_4$, we lose one dimension in the first factor while nothing happens in the second one, so this is a measure zero set.
(This answer assumes the result about the eigenvalues being distinct almost everywhere.)

This is the answer that I understand the best, but I'm going to accept SeanC's answer because it came first.

Yet another way to prove this kind of facts is to record that we have a formula for the eigenvalue distribution of a GUE random matrix (called the Ginebre law according to Terry Tao's blog). It has an explicit and strictly positive density with respect to
Lebesgue measure on the Weyl chamber $W_n=\{(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)\mid\lambda_1\geq \dots\geq\lambda_n) \}$.
In particular, the image of the Lebesgue measure class on Hermitian matrices by the eigenvalue map is the Lebesgue measure class on $W_n$.

Oh, this is nice!
